# Codeigniter form validation

Tags: codeigniter

I`m using codeigniter validation class when submit forms. Also I`m using set_value() to re-populate fields on form fails. If I have

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required')
```

set_value() works and field is re-populated. But what if I don`t won`t the field to be required ? If I do not add  $this->form_validation* re-populating is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website-lab's post is correct - it's a feature of CI that no `set_value($foo)` are returned unless there is a validation rule.

If you don't want to have empty validation rules, there are a few hacks available and you can extend the form helper

this thread has a lot of information -

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/96617/P15/#689642

I also believe you can just use

`$this->input->post('my_field')`

in your view, if using empty validations or hacking the core doesn't appeal to you.

Comment: Great answer -- also helped me with my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Include the field form in the validation class but do not set any rules for it.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('someField', '', '');
```

This field data will now work with `set_value` but wont have any validation rules run across it.